# Is it possible to modify datatypes in tables of Apache Ignite without restart?

Tags: ignite

Faced an issue with Ignite while needed to modify datatype in my Ignite database. It's no problem to set a new config at the start of the nodes, however, there could be a situations when restart of the whole Ignite is kinda overkill.
Tried to destroy topic with destroy() and destroyCache(), but it cleared only content keeping the old data structure.

I'm starting to think that Ignite simply is not able to do that kind of operation, but need to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can drop table and create new table as needed. You can also destroy cache and start new cache. You can also add columns to SQL tables. And then you can also put instances of new-and-improved types into existing caches.

There's so many options that I will probably ask for an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Tho get cache with another data structure you need to [create](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jcache#section-dynamic-cache) another one and copy data to it with required transformations, after that destroy first one.

SQL for now doesn't support column drop, but adding new one. But if it was, you'd be able to do transformations quite similar to regular DB. Maybe it would be added in future releases.

Anyway, there is no simple way to do that.